# Install 10.6 over 10.5 on iMac

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac, imac, upgrade

Currently my iMac has 10.5.8 Mac Os X installed.

I want to install 10.6.6 over 10.5.8 (iMac (intel Dual core)).

Do I have to do the following ??

1. Visit Apple Store.
2. Buy 10.6 OS X for USD $29.00
3. Simply insert installation disk in the computer and follow and execute install instructions.
4. All the existing applications (including FinalCutExpress) will continue to work as usual.

Please confirm.

Thanks..

Comment: Your iMac has an Intel processor, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're correct about steps 1 thru 3. You're mostly correct for step 4.**

Once you install the new OS, you won't lose any data or settings or anything like that.

However, know that not all apps are 10.6-compatible. Almost all are, but not everything is.

[Here's a wiki](http://snowleopard.wikidot.com/) with info about which apps are compatible.

Again, most are, but you may have a few that won't work, or will work poorly.

Basically, just be careful. Check your important software first.
As for Final Cut Express: I can't imagine that any recent version wouldn't be compatible (Apple makes Final Cut and OS X).

Answer (score 4):

To offer you a different point of view: I assume you're going to have a Backup of your system before performing such a drastic operation.

If you do have a backup, I strongly advice you to install Snow Leopard from scratch and then, using migration assistant, transfer your data from your backup (Time Machine or clone).

I have upgraded seven machines from Leopard to Snow Leopard. Three with the method you describe and four with a fresh install.

I had problems with two of the upgraded machines (that eventually had to be reinstalled) and zero problems with the fresh installs.

That's my experience and ymmv, but bear in mind that the changes to the underlying system between Leopard and Snow Leopard justify a fresh start :)

You can always try the upgrade, but always have a backup, there are a lot of things that -depending upon your system- can fail.

Answer (score 0):

though you can do it, and most stuff will still work, "updating" a system on top of another system is never good.  at the very least, disk usage will not be efficient.

it is always best to format your disk and install from scratch.

in case you have a version of snow leopard that doesnt work (is not accepted by your machine because of hardware version restrictions), check out [THIS TÜTORIAL](http://www.hackint0sh.org/genuine-mac-support-147/guide-w-pictures-installing-os-x-non-retail-un-supported-macs-109587.htm), which will work as long as your machine is fit to run snow leopard (list available online).